# Model paths by regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, computation-models

I want use DFA to describe a sequence of movements in a 2D-space (language will be  the path accepted by automaton in a particular case).

That is a typical modeling problem: how can I encode a sequence of 2D movements in a DFA?

Infact, walking through DFA or NFA seems a process analogous to walk through point of a maps.

A naives example could be: State like point in space coordinate (x,y); and  Transitions with an alphabet of "up, down, etc".
That's direct approach is impracticable beacuse "the number of locations is infinite or simply too many". I'm looking for a better and more efficient encoding.

Are there any study about using regular languages for coding path, or movements?

Comment: What do you mean by "walk through point of a map"?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. Please read
http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour.if you have not yet done so. When
posting a question, make sure to give enough context, and show how you tried to answer it on your own, so as to be very precise regarding
your problem. This helps better answers. In this case it would help to understand what you are trying to achieve? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Regular languages are languages. That means they are sets of
strings. So in this case they could be used to define sets of paths,
not single paths (not usefully anyway).

Comment: Thank's, i improved the question.

You are in the right way: one strings should be a single path, and a language a set of paths sharing all the same structure/syntax

Comment: This problem is too vague as it stands.  Please add additional context.  How will you evaluate answers?  What counts as an acceptable solution?  You list one naive approach but then reject it without explaining why.  Why is it impracticable?  What's wrong with it?  I worry that you'll just reject any other answer we give you.  We expect you to state all your requirements in the question, so that anyone can judge whether answers meet your requirements.  (Also, why do you want something "more sophisticated"?  That seems like exactly the wrong approach -- remember the KISS principle.)

Comment: Well, I am not sure this is what you wish, but you can look at the article D. Giammaresi, A. Restivo, [Two-dimensional languages](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~giammarr/Research/Papers/chap96.ps.Z) In A. Salomaa, G. Rozenberg (Eds.), Handbook of Formal Languages, Vol. 3, Beyond Words, Springer, Berlin, 1997, pp. 215–267.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is, let alone what the question about it should be.

Comment: "How will you evaluate answers? What counts as an acceptable solution?"
A grammar is a description of a language, then acceptable solution are subset of strings defining the particular language. In our case "a sequence of movements in a 2D-space" valid for the particular language.

More interesting is why naive approach is impracticable: as correct wrote @doganulus, problems arise beacuse " the number of locations is infinite or simply too many".

I'm going to improve again the question, thank's for suggestions!

J.-E.Pin Thanks, i didn't know 2D languages! I'm reading...

Comment: @D.W. 
Maybe, now that there is also an answer where someone understand the question you could remove the "on hold state".

Comment: The encoding of a sequence into a DFA is essentially the sequence itself, in the sense that the DFA has to define the singleton set containing the sequence. I think you have your modeling mixed up in your head. The only useful DFA I see is the one describing your map, i.e. the set of all possible motions, depending on where you are.

Comment: robott, we expect you to edit the question to add the clarifications (don't just leave clarifications in the comments; people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand the question).  That said, I still don't understand what you're asking or what the requirements are, personally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of locations (e.g. points or regions) are finite, naively, you can say that these locations are my states and you can directly use a DFA with an alphabet containing UP, DOWN. But you already said it's impracticable for your case.

Then, let's look into where the number of locations is infinite or simply too many. Basically, in this case, you need to recognize that the sequences UP-DOWN, UP-UP-DOWN-DOWN, UP-UP-UP-DOWN-DOWN-DOWN ... etc. are equivalent because equal number of UP and DOWNs gets you back to the starting point. This is the classical example of non-regular languages. Therefore I suggest you looking into other automata such as counter machines if they are sufficient to capture your intentions.

Comment: Welcome to CS Stack Exchange!

Comment: Thank's! That is exactly what I meant!
Could you suggest some papers about or author who investigate this problems?
I'm looking for similar problems tractable with regular languages :)

Comment: Well I always found this paper interesting [Adding Nesting Structure to Words](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~alur/Jacm09.pdf) and besides check its references.